# getElementById is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have this [**simple**](http://jsbin.com/UsIpILe/2/edit) html markup:

```
<form id="form" action="lalala">
  <input type="text" id="action"/>  //a reserved property name id
  <input type="submit" id="submit"/> //same here
</form>
```

However -- running :

`alert(document.getElementById('form').action);`

alerts

[image]

and not "lalala" like it should.

It seems that`getElementById`'s props is not accessed directly

Why is that ? ..... it can actually mean that I have to know all the form element's props (in order not to provide reserved prop ID to a descendant element) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `getElementById` and everything to do with the properties of an HTML Form Element object.

> a reserved property name id

It isn't "reserved", it just has a value defined by default

If you have a form control in a form, and that control has an id (or name) that matches a property that form elements have, then a reference to that form control will overwrite the normal value of that property.

> When a form element is indexed for indexed property retrieval, the user agent must return the value returned by the item method on the elements collection, when invoked with the given index as its argument.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

This sucks, but is how the DOM for forms has worked since there was such a thing.

Since that particular property maps on to an attribute value, you can use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` to manipulate it instead. (This won't work in old IE (which has a broken implementation of those methods that operate on properties) and won't work for some other properties (like the submit method)).

> it can actually mean that I have to know all the form element's props (in order not to provide reserved prop ID to a descendant element)

Yes.

Comment: Does it happens for both props and attributes ? cuz I see that `action` is a property and not an attribute.  (http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJPHB.png)

Comment: @RoyiNamir — I said: Since that particular property maps on to an attribute value, you can use getAttribute and setAttribute to manipulate it instead. (This won't work in old IE (which has a broken implementation of those methods that operate on properties) and won't work for some other properties (like the submit method)).

Answer (score 4):

try like this :

```
alert(document.getElementById('form').getAttribute("action"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it through attributes:

`document.getElementById('form').attributes["action"].value`

Answer (score 1):

You can't write .action in this situation because you should access it threw it's attribute and not property, this is an attribute, therefore, you need to getAttribute instead and it will work :)

```
alert(document.getElementById('form').getAttribute("action"));
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, this is correct. I see that Royi has since removed his comment about it being incorrect though.

Comment: @JamieTaylor But I see that action _is_ a property and not attribute http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJPHB.png

Comment: There is an action property and an action attribute. Claiming that action is not a property is wrong.